# C# HttpWebRequest problem

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

This is kind of weird problem. I have been using HttpWebRequest for a long time now. But never faced this problem before. The site I am scrapping is huge in size, atleast 3mb each page.

> In xp it is giving no error but
>   scrapping incomplete page.

In win7 or 2008 server it is showing this error

> "Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host"

. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I believe it is possible to disable loading the images from a website, that should reduce size dramatically (if you don't need the images that is)

Comment: @Pieter888 - The `HttpWebRequest` will only get the markup, not any linked resources (i.e. no js, css or image files).

Comment: @Pieter888: I am only downloading the html page not any other links into the page [ie. picture/ animations].

Comment: Oh my bad, I mistook `HttpWebRequest` for the `WebBrowser` my bad. I guess you should check out the `KeepAlive` attribute then.

Comment: @Pieter888- How shall I do that ?

Comment: Could be that there's a security policy in place that disconnects you based on browser ID, or as a result of the sort of automated activity you've been doing. Did it ever work on this site? Can you still hit it with a regular browser? I've written code on sites that bans IP addresses temporarily based on certain obvious automated attack patterns, but only at the application level (e.g. just disconnects them after each request) which would probably cause this kind of effect.

Comment: I'm no expert so I don't even know if it has got anything to do with it (that's why I'm not posting it as an anwer) but this could help you out: `myHttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;`

Comment: @jamietre - Yes with regular browser all data are coming without any problems.

Comment: If not already, try setting `UserAgent` to something standard just to be sure it's not rejecting unrecognized user agents.

Comment: @Barun: I believe that if you **[activate network tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx)** or install a local HTTP sniffer, you could find out quickly what's going on (something probably related to how data chunks are sent and/or HTTP 100-Continue server response).

Comment: @jamietre - Yes already set this header. Still same problem.

Comment: @Maxim Gueivandov - yes I already tracked data. No difference between my packet and browser packet.

Comment: Hmm. I guess I'd echo @barun, Fiddler2 is a very easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending 5 days on it I come to this conclusion that this is a big bug of .net
And atlast I solved this problem using WebBrowser component. Though  I dont like it very much because it does not work outside of main thread. But it is really fast and scrapping those pages like a champ.

Comment: can you explane it. i have same problem

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue with the ISP serving the pages filtering HTTP GET requests.

Try adding the following ACCEPT header:

```
webRequest.Accept = "*/*";
```

Answer (score 0):

The webserver or a man-in-the-middle e.g. a proxy is killing your connection.  I take it this request works fine in a browser.  I'd do a few things:

1. It's a lot of data - make sure your timeouts (Timeout and ReadWriteTimeout) are set suitably high.
2. Make this request look like it originated from a real browser- use a tool like Fiddler or Netmon to extract and copy the headers from a browser making the same request - UserAgent, Accepts, Content-Encoding etc.  Seen lots of sites vomit when standard headers are missing.
3. Cookies may be important (some sites use it for basic DDoS prevention) - again use Fiddler to observe the real browser interaction.

> [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/version.asp)
>
> [NetMon](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en)

Let us know how you got on.

Comment: Already did all these things. I think this is the problem with HttpWebRequest class. May be this is a bug.